# mat-select disabled is not picking up on the variable from the scope in angular5

Tags: angular-material, angular5

```
<div class="bulk-actions-container">
  {{ selectedInstances.length }}
    <mat-select placeholder="{{'common.bulk.actions.title'| translate }}" disabled="selectedInstances.length === 0">
        <mat-option [value]="'dueDate'">Change Due Date</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</div>
```

Strange situation for sure. `selectedInstances.length` is showing as `1`, but the `mat-select` is still disabled. What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't specified that the disabled property is bound to an expression. Your code is setting the property value to the string `selectedInstances.length === 0` which is truthy when evaluated as a boolean. Try `[disabled]="selectedInstances.length === 0"` or `disabled="{{selectedInstances.length === 0}}"`